# AtMega328p A/D inaccuracy

Tags: adc, atmega328p, overclocking

I'm getting A/D readings from an AtMega328p chip that are about 10% higher than I can read on the input signal with a meter.

I'm measuring room temperature with an LM34CZ Fahrenheit temperature sensor (10mv/degF) output. The sensor has a 5v supply. The chip is running on 3.3 volts derived from the same 5v supply with an LM1117 regulator, but the crystal a 16MHz one which is out of spec for the chip (Fmax at 3.3v is about 12MHz). The chip is otherwise apparently running properly and has done for hours to days at a time. I've checked both supplies with a meter - they're within mV of where they should be.

The A/D is using its internal 1.1v reference with an external .1uF cap from AREF to ground. The sensor and chip grounds and the two supply grounds are all common. The analog signal from the sensor has maybe a 2cm run to the A5 input pin on the chip.

Acknowledging that I'm using a part out of spec, does anyone see a plausible reason for the A/D to read high in this circumstance?

Update: To those wondering why I'd expect a device, operated out of spec, to yet perform to spec, I held no such expectation. I was prepared for anything from instability to a totally non-functional device. That it runs at all, let alone stably, is a pleasant surprise. Given that, I thought it useful to look for a slightly better explanation for the errors than "Beyond here there be dragons". Dragons there may be, but this time at least, they seem to have held their fiery breath - the issues lay elsewhere, specifically, with the sensor.

Comment: Did you set the ADC clock to an appropriate frequency?

Comment: So you are using an out of spec crystal and wondering about out of spec behaviour?

Comment: Read the data sheet - it is a crappy ADC and a colleague has fallen foul of it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: No change to any clock freqs, just to Vcc.  PlasmaHH: Yes, as asked. Andyaka: Yes and I'll have another look; thanks. Is your assessment of it directed at any spec in particular?

Comment: The internal Vref varies greatly, the datasheet specifies anywhere from 1.0 - 1.2 V.  That could count for the majority of the error.  Have you measured what it actually is on the Vref pin?

Comment: I measured Aref and found 1.081V; low but not enough to make the difference I saw. I just swapped sensors and I'm now reading temperatures that compare to a hardware store thermometer, allowing for the tolerances of both sensors. Even better when I correct for low Aref. It looks like my original sensor was not only off, but inconsistent. @justing: Your comment gave me about 1/2 the answer and led me to find the rest. If you'll make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: For reference: http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8060.pdf

Comment: Thank you - that's very useful. I'm about to add a simple per-chip scale-factor now that I see it's needed. A full multiplier/offset calibration is more than I need at present but the day will come....

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling the ADC noise canceler sleep mode.  This turns off other sections of the chip briefly, to allow a cleaner, more accurate reading.  In this case, if the problem is being caused by a slight undervoltage by being out of spec.

Please allow me to emphasise the IF.  This is a guess - I'll be watching this question to see if this helps...

Comment: The conversion isn't very noisy - a couple of LSB at the most - with no more measures than keeping the signal paths short.